Unable to Establish Socket.IO Connection Between Flutter App and Node.js Server
I have developed a Flutter chat application that communicates with a Node.js server using Socket.IO. The Node.js server is responsible for managing connections, joining users to specific rooms based on sender and receiver IDs, and relaying messages between clients. However, I'm encountering an issue where the Flutter app is unable to establish a connection with the Node.js server. Despite implementing the necessary connection logic in both the server and the app, the connection is not being established, and messages are not being exchanged. I have verified that the server is running and listening on the correct port.
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const app = express();
const authRouter = require("./routes/auth");
const updateRouter = require("./routes/update_user");
const statusRouter = require("./routes/status");
const http = require("http");
const path = require("path");
const socketIo = require("socket.io");
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIo(server);
// Serve uploaded profile images statically
app.use("/uploads", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "uploads")));

//process.env.PORT ||
const PORT = 3000;
`node js socket io code `
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("User connected");

  socket.on("join", (data) => {
    const { senderId, receiverId } = data;
    const roomId = `${senderId}_${receiverId}`;
    socket.join(roomId);
    console.log(`User ${senderId} joined room ${roomId}`);
  });

  socket.on("message", (data) => {
    const { senderId, receiverId, message } = data;
    const roomId = `${senderId}_${receiverId}`;
    io.to(roomId).emit("message", { senderId, message });
  });

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("User disconnected");
  });
});

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URL)
  .then(() => {
    console.log("mongoDB connected");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
app.use(express.json());
app.use(authRouter);
app.use(updateRouter);
app.use(statusRouter);
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`connect at ${PORT}`);
});

and this is node js dependecy versions
"dependencies": {
    "socket.io": "^4.7.5"
  }      

and  this is my flutter  code
import 'package:amezone/constants/api_url.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:socket_io_client/socket_io_client.dart' as IO;

class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String receiverId;
  final String senderId;

  ChatScreen({Key? key, required this.senderId, required this.receiverId})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ChatScreenState createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}

class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  final List<String> _messages = [];
  late IO.Socket socket;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    connect();
  }

  void connect() {
`and the flutter base url is local host "http://10.0.2.2:3000"`
    socket = IO.io(baseUrl, <String, dynamic>{
      "transports": ["websocket"],
      "autoConnect": false,
    });

    socket.connect();
    socket.onConnect((data) {
      print('connected');
      // Join room with sender and receiver IDs
      socket.emit('join',
          {'senderId': widget.senderId, 'receiverId': widget.receiverId});
    });

    socket.on('message', (data) {
      final senderId = data['senderId'];
      final message = data['message'];
      setState(() {
        _messages.add('$senderId: $message');
      });
    });
    print(socket.connected);
  }

  void _sendMessage(String message) {
    socket.emit('message', {
      'senderId': widget.senderId,
      'receiverId': widget.receiverId,
      'message': message
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Socket.IO Chat'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: _messages.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(_messages[index]),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: _controller,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter message'),
                  ),
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.send),
                  onPressed: () {
                    _sendMessage(_controller.text);
                    _controller.clear();
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    socket.disconnect();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

and this is socket version of flutter socket_io_client: ^2.0.3+1
